# jenkins pylint cannot find log file

Tags: python, jenkins, pylint

I've just started to look at Jenkins CI and tried to integrate it with python pylint according to [this](http://www.alexconrad.org/2011/10/jenkins-and-python.html) manual.

The problem is that Jenkins violations plugin cannot find the pylint config file OR it cannot interpret it.
I've already tried to use absolute paths to pylint log but no luck.
I've also tried to turn on some detailed logging to figure the problem. But no luck either
The only output message from jenkin's pylint is:

```
pylint <span style='color:red'>No reports</span>
```

The pylint output log looks like this:

```
************* Module dbmanager
dbmanager.py:107: [C0301(line-too-long), ] Line too long (113/80)
dbmanager.py:108: [C0301(line-too-long), ] Line too long (109/80)
dbmanager.py:110: [C0301(line-too-long), ] Line too long (112/80)
dbmanager.py:122: [C0301(line-too-long), ] Line too long (106/80)
dbmanager.py:129: [C0301(line-too-long), ] Line too long (113/80)
dbmanager.py:130: [C0301(line-too-long), ] Line too long (109/80)
dbmanager.py:132: [C0301(line-too-long), ] Line too long (111/80)
dbmanager.py:145: [C0301(line-too-long), ] Line too long (82/80)
dbmanager.py:156: [C0301(line-too-long), ] Line too long (83/80)
dbmanager.py:163: [C0301(line-too-long), ] Line too long (90/80)
dbmanager.py:16: [W0602(global-variable-not-assigned), init] Using global for '_CFG' but no assignment is done
dbmanager.py:25: [W0602(global-variable-not-assigned), check_user] Using global for '_DB' but no assignment is done
dbmanager.py:53: [W0602(global-variable-not-assigned), get_deposit] Using global for '_DB' but no assignment is done
dbmanager.py:62: [W0602(global-variable-not-assigned), get_deposit2] Using global for '_DB' but no assignment is done
dbmanager.py:71: [W0602(global-variable-not-assigned), set_deposit] Using global for '_DB' but no assignment is done
dbmanager.py:78: [W0602(global-variable-not-assigned), get_uid] Using global for '_DB' but no assignment is done
dbmanager.py:87: [W0602(global-variable-not-assigned), check_tid] Using global for '_DB' but no assignment is done
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've done it. The the but don't know how :)
I think there were 2 problems:

1. rcfile. There must have been some misconfiguration
2. path to reports file. I've used absolute path and that was wrong. After I've changed it to **/pylint.report. It all started to work

Comment: could you share pylintrc file?

Comment: Unfortunately that server have been down for a long time

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the pylint config with

```
--rcfile=/path/to/file
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Nope, this did not help either

Comment: Could you post your pylint config file then?